# What does kingfish play?

Tags: electric-guitar, scales, blues, rock-n-roll

I've just discovered a new amazing guitar player, Christone Kingfish Ingram, since the first time I was shocked by the way he plays. I've tried everything but I simply don't understand what he plays, he is able to play a high amount of different notes which are not part of the pentatonic or classic blues scales, and despite this he keeps the song very blues style. I simply do not understand which scales he plays or which kind of "algorithm" he is using.
Maybe this link can help you understand what I mean:

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a mix of "specific equipment request" and "finding a particular..."

Comment: Where is the equipment request?